# How to add analytics for Push notifications

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, web-push, progressive-web-apps, push-api

I'm working on progressive web app, and I want to implement analytics for Push notifications.

How can I add analytics for push notifications so that I'll be able to track and record how many people clicked on notification and how many people close that notification without clicking on it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've written a small chunk of code to use Google analytics for analytics and it works fairly well.

Dumped notes here: https://gauntface.com/blog/2016/05/01/push-debugging-analytics

---

The way I've done this is the post mentioned above:

In the service worker I import a javascript file that does the tracking for me, set the analytics ID and then in the appropriate events call the tracking. Look for `self.analytics.trackEvent`:

```js
importScripts('./scripts/analytics.js');

self.analytics.trackingId = 'UA-77119321-2';

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  let notificationTitle = 'Hello';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Thanks for sending this push msg.',
    icon: './images/icon-192x192.png',
    tag: 'simple-push-demo-notification'
  };

  // Important to trigger analytics asynchronously with logic
  // to show notification
  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      self.analytics.trackEvent('push-received'),
      self.registration.showNotification('Hello', notificationOptions)
    ])
  );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();

  // Important to trigger analytics asynchronously with logic
  // to do other work (i.e. open window)
  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      self.analytics.trackEvent('notification-click'),
      clients.openWindow('https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/')
    ])
  );
});
```

The code to do the actual tracking calls to Google Analytics Measurements Protocol is shown below. The API is painfully simplistic, so the payloadData are the attributes analytics expects and I generate a string of these parameters in the format the API expects, filtering out empty / null values:

```js
class Analytics {
  trackEvent(eventAction, eventValue) {
    if (!this.trackingId) {
      console.error('You need to set a trackingId, for example:');
      console.error('self.analytics.trackingId = \'UA-XXXXXXXX-X\';');

      // We want this to be a safe method, so avoid throwing Unless
      // It's absolutely necessary.
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    if (!eventAction && !eventValue) {
      console.warn('sendAnalyticsEvent() called with no eventAction or ' +
      'eventValue.');
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then(subscription => {
      if (subscription === null) {
        // The user has not subscribed yet.
        throw new Error('No subscription currently available.');
      }

      const payloadData = {
        // GA Version Number
        v: 1,
        // Client ID
        cid: subscription.endpoint,
        // Tracking ID
        tid: this.trackingId,
        // Hit Type
        t: 'event',
        // Data Source
        ds: 'serviceworker',
        // Event Category
        ec: 'serviceworker',
        // Event Action
        ea: eventAction,
        // Event Value
        ev: eventValue
      };

      const payloadString = Object.keys(payloadData)
      .filter(analyticsKey => {
        return payloadData[analyticsKey];
      })
      .map(analyticsKey => {
        return `${analyticsKey}=` +
          encodeURIComponent(payloadData[analyticsKey]);
      })
      .join('&');

      return fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', {
        method: 'post',
        body: payloadString
      });
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return response.text()
        .then(responseText => {
          throw new Error(
            `Bad response from Google Analytics ` +
            `[${response.status}] ${responseText}`);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn('Unable to send the analytics event', err);
    });
  }
}

if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
  self.analytics = new Analytics();
}
```

You can find all of this on: https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo

Comment: very helpful notes..........Thank you @gaunt face. one more thing i'm getting  active users on notification_click event.can i also get report that how many users received notification

Comment: Yeah just add another event in the push event - will pad out the answer with some code sample.

Comment: @MattGaunt Is there anyway to send analytics for different stages for mac safari push notifications..thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by different stages? I'm also not up to date on safari push - are you referring to service worker web push or safari's custom push notifications?

Comment: @MattGaunt we faced one issue in GA when we implemented the analytics for push notification. Issue is ::: events are registered in GA through the collect api for push received , clicked , closed through the events "push", "notificationclick", "notificationclose"in sw.js... then in GA dashboard we got the warning message stating that "Verify that tracking code for property example.com sends a pageview hit before sending any events" and we stopped receiving push events in GA after some time... is it related to the warning we got in GA dashboard as mentioned here or no of hit to the collect api

Answer (score 1):

An option, that I'm using in my [WordPress web-push plugin](https://github.com/mozilla/wp-web-push), is to add a query argument to the URLs opened via notifications (see [this code](https://github.com/mozilla/wp-web-push/blob/c7e67383a4aa870b57bacca16df87fff0ccd5e36/wp-web-push/lib/js/sw.php#L31)). This way, you can know how many times people click on notifications.

About the number of people that close notifications, it's unfortunately not possible to know. There's a [`notificationclose` event](https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/pull/61), but it is only triggered for persistent notifications.

Answer (score 1):

At [Pushpad](https://pushpad.xyz) the notification url is a **redirect page** that tracks the opening and then redirects to the target url.

For example if the target url is `http://example.com/target` your notification url that is opened on click should be `http://example.com/redirect?url=/target`.

At the moment there is no way to track when the notification is dismissed.

**Update (June 2016)**: others have pointed out that in the specs there's a [`notificationclose` event](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#closing-a-notification). However I haven't tested browser support (currently this event is not listed on MDN for example). Beside that I fear that this event can also be triggered when the user clicks the notification (since the notification gets closed) - the spec is not clear about that.

Comment: notificationclose event (As mentioned by Marco) allows you to track dismiss.

Comment: @GauntFace Nope, check out MDN documentation for the Push API for example: currently (June 2016) there's no such event.

Comment: @GauntFace You're right! However I don't know if it's supported by browsers right now: have you tried it?

Comment: @GauntFace Furthermore I don't know if the `close` event implies that the notification is dismissed: **maybe it's also called when the user clicks the notification** and the notification gets closed. For example for compatibility with the first versions of Chrome you explicitly call `event.notification.close();` when the user clicks the notification (and maybe this triggers the close event).

Comment: I got round to testing this, it works in Chrome 51+ but I don't believe any of the other browsers support this at the moment.